# CSS Styles not being picked up with class defined as parent

Tags: css

I have some CSS styles defined in a style sheet that are not being picked up on the page.

The page renders a telerik component which uses these styles.  However, the table that wraps around the page, I applied a "telerikEditor" class to.

If I remove "telerkEditor" from the style sheet everywhere then it works, but it doesn't work as it is shown below.

I am confused as I thought I could narrow down the styles to anything within a telerikEditor class as the parent and it would apply these styles to it's children.

Am I doing this wrong?

```
telerikEditor .t-icon { background-image: url('Default/sprite.png'); }
telerikEditor .t-editor .t-tool-icon { background-image: url('Default/editor.png'); }

telerikEditor .t-loading,
telerikEditor .t-widget .t-loading { background: transparent url('Default/loading.gif') no-repeat 0 0; }

telerikEditor .t-widget,
telerikEditor .t-link:link,
telerikEditor .t-link:active,
telerikEditor .t-link:visited,
telerikEditor .t-popup
{
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

telerikEditor is a css class? If so then put a dot as first char.

Eg

`.telerikEditor .t-icon { background-image: url('Default/sprite.png'); }`